# Shopping cart checkout with JQuery draggable + droppable?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, draggable

I'm trying to make a drag + drop shopping cart and have looked into two options: [JQuery UI draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) and [Scriptaculous Draggable + Rails Helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/ScriptaculousHelper.html), but I'm having difficulty tying controller actions to items that have been dragged into the shopping cart.

E.g. I want users to drag items into the cart div, then click 'checkout' and continue on to providing payment information for all the items, etc...

Currently in my db I have a column that accepts the multiple item ids that they want to purchase as a hash. I've also tinkered with setting it up as a form with hidden fields, but this might not be the best choice.

Any ideas on how I could achieve this? Example code would be awesome if possible. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JQuery UI Droppable would work well. There is an example of using it for a shopping cart here:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#shopping-cart

To integrate with Rails 3, one approach is to treat the page as a traditional (non-AJAX) web form, but use Javascript to manipulate hidden input elements.

1. Use JSON to populate a JavaScript array/object with your data (your data model)
2. Use Javascript with JQuery to manipulate the model
3. Use a small Javascript function to write the model out to hidden input elements that are correctly named for Rails - the function gets run every time the data is changed
4. Submit the form as usual when a submit button is clicked

Comment: Appreciate the help! I've gotten steps 1,3, and 4 to work, but I'm still a bit confused how to do part 2? I dont get how I can correctly tie each item div (id?) dragged into the cart div to the hidden input? I have a to_json hash with all the items ids and I'm using .val ()